# Is there any function which can clear all the data in the /dev/input/event* file?

Tags: c, linux, embedded

Now I'm developing some software in the embedded Linux platform, I have some physical push buttons which I can read their pressing event through the file `/dev/input/event1`, in some special cases, I have to clear all event data stored in `/dev/input/event1`, but I don't know how.

Comment: The function is `read()`. `read()` from the file until there is nothing to read.

Comment: Thank you, but is there any function like `fflush()` or `tcflush()` to clear the key event buffer?

Comment: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/drivers/input/evdev.c#L1292 doesn't look like that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open the file in non-blocking mode and `read()` until there is nothing more to read. Use a buffer of PAGESIZE or 4K for efficiency.